# Configuration of pmadb... not OK Error in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin

I know this question has been asked here a number of times, and I went through all the answers I could find but nothing seems to work for me.

I recently downloaded PhpMyAdmin and MySQL. Everything works fine except when I log into phpMyAdmin as a root user, I get this error:

```
"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
```

When I click to find out why, I get this:

```
Configuration of pmadb... not OK
General relation features Disabled
Create a database named phpmyadmin and setup the phpMyAdmin configuration storage there.
```

The phpmyadmin database exists, however I do not know how to setup configuration storage there.

What I tried:
Uncommenting lines under /* User used to manipulate with storage */ and /* Storage database and tables */ in config.inc.php file - no luck.

Others also suggest creating a user 'pma'@'localhost' in create_tables.sql file but I cannot locate this file anywhere. I also created this user in the "user" table of "mysql" database, so it may do the same thing as creating it in create_tables.sql file.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Everything seems to be working fine, this error is just annoying. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When I got this issue, I simply fixed it by selecting the stock "mysql" database, and in the "Tables" view, bottom left, "Check all" tables, then change "With selected:" dropdown to "Repair table".

[image]